# Reading CSV before appending to stop duplicates

Tags: python, csv

Project consists of using the YT api to list all youtube videos in a playlist and later downloading the video.
Im using a CSV file to ensure that the same video (same video_id) is not downloaded again by appending the video_id to the CSV.

```
with open('video-id.csv','a+',newline='') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
```

*youtube api code*

```
for video in videos["items"]:
    video_id = video["contentDetails"]["videoId"]

    if video_id in reader:
        print('duplicate')
    
    elif video_id not in csv_file:
        # converts the videoID to a link shich can be used by pytube module
        video_url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + video_id

        # defines url for the pytube module
        video = YouTube(video_url)

        # only returns 'streams' which are soley 'audio' using the 'first' one in the list (highest audio bitrate)
        video_stream = video.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()

        print('Downloading',video_title + '...')

        video_stream.download()

        # appends id to csv to ensure the video is not downloaded again
        writer.writerow({video_id})
```

The CVS file is being appended successfully but the same video_id's are being appended every time the script is run and I am struggling to find a way to check the csv file for a matching video_id to stop this from happening.

CVS file:

```
hi9_oyKAAds
b3T4b3GCRk4
hi9_oyKAAds
b3T4b3GCRk4
hi9_oyKAAds
b3T4b3GCRk4
hi9_oyKAAds
b3T4b3GCRk4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope next comments would be helpful:

1. When you first read file like `video_id in reader`, then to re-read it again you need to move "slider" to the beginning of the file with `seek()` method:

   ```py
   csv_file.seek(0,0) # offset=0, whence=0 (beginning of the file)
   ```
2. When you checking video_id in reader (`video_id in reader`) take a notice that item from reader is a list:

   ```py
   for item in reader:
     print(item)
   ```

   will return:

   ```
   ['hi9_oyKAAds']
   ['b3T4b3GCRk4']
   ...
   ```
3. if you iterate with csv_file (in your code — `video_id not in csv_file`) then take a notice it contain `\r\n` chars, like this:

   ```
   for item in csv_file:
     print(repr(item))
   ```

   will return

   ```
   'hi9_oyKAAds\r\n'
   'b3T4b3GCRk4\r\n'
   ```